# MongoLab Connection Issues in Android App Using MongoDB Async Driver 3.0.2

Tags: java, android, mongodb, driver

Simply put I can't connect. I've followed the documentation and I seem to be getting lots of errors.

Errors

```
05-31 15:26:24.062  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 18243: Ljavax/management/ObjectName;.quote (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
05-31 15:26:24.062  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17794: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getRuntimeMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean;
05-31 15:26:24.092  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/org.bson.ObjectId﹕ Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
            at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:502)
            at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:460)
            at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:40)
            at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.createCluster(MongoClients.java:96)
            at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:55)
            at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:75)
            at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:65)
            at com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic.MainActivity.MongoDBConnection(MainActivity.java:287)
            at com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 15:26:24.092  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ds043082.mongolab.com:43082], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
05-31 15:26:24.102  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17793: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getPlatformMBeanServer ()Ljavax/management/MBeanServer;
05-31 15:26:24.102  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.internal.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.registerMBean
05-31 15:26:24.102  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2774 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/internal/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
05-31 15:26:24.102  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.management.ObjectName', referenced from method com.mongodb.internal.management.jmx.JMXMBeanServer.unregisterMBean
05-31 15:26:24.102  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2774 (Ljavax/management/ObjectName;) in Lcom/mongodb/internal/management/jmx/JMXMBeanServer;
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=ds043082.mongolab.com:43082, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel;)
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17891: Ljava/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel;.close ()V
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 17893: Ljava/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel;.open ()Ljava/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel;
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler;' failed
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler', referenced from method com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.readAsync
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1973 (Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler;) in Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream;
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$1;' failed
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$1;' failed
05-31 15:26:24.112  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/mongodb/connection/AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler;' failed
05-31 15:26:24.122  15970-15983/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ds043082.mongolab.com:43082
    com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: Opening the AsynchronousSocketChannelStream failed
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.get(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:65)
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.getOpen(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:43)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:60)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.openAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:67)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:59)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:26:54.114  15970-15984/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/System.out﹕ Operation Finished!
05-31 15:26:54.134  15970-15984/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/System.out﹕ listDatabaseNames() errored: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ds043082.mongolab.com:43082, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: Opening the AsynchronousSocketChannelStream failed}, caused by {java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel}}]
05-31 15:26:54.194  15970-16200/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic D/libc﹕ [net] no pids to match num= 99
05-31 15:26:54.314  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/MainActivity﹕ Ready
05-31 15:26:54.404  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ds043082.mongolab.com:43082], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
05-31 15:26:54.404  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=ds043082.mongolab.com:43082, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
05-31 15:26:54.404  15970-16215/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ds043082.mongolab.com:43082
    com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: Opening the AsynchronousSocketChannelStream failed
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.get(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:65)
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.getOpen(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:43)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:60)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.openAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:67)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:59)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:26:54.414  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ds043082.mongolab.com:43082], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
05-31 15:26:54.424  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=ds043082.mongolab.com:43082, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
05-31 15:26:54.434  15970-16217/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/cluster﹕ Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ds043082.mongolab.com:43082
    com.mongodb.MongoInternalException: Opening the AsynchronousSocketChannelStream failed
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.get(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:65)
            at com.mongodb.connection.FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.getOpen(FutureAsyncCompletionHandler.java:43)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:60)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.openAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:67)
            at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.open(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:59)
            at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
            at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:26:54.454  15970-15970/com.example.android.slidingtabsbasic I/Adreno200-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:269>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL2858274)
    Build Date: 12/24/12 Mon
    Local Branch: D1L_VWZ1211_RB4_AU37-1738J
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
```

Here is the code I'm executing to attempt to make the connection. I'm confused as to weather or not I actually need to provide my login information for the connection string? I have tried both and they both result in errors but I'd like to actually know when I'd use my credentials and when i wouldn't?

```
public void MongoDBConnection() throws InterruptedException{

        //Makes Connection to Database

        mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://xxx:xxx**X@theConnection/database");
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        SingleResultCallback<Void> callbackWhenFinished = new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Operation Finished!");
                if (t != null) {
                    System.out.println("listDatabaseNames() errored: " + t.getMessage());
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };

        mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(new Block<String>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(final String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }, callbackWhenFinished);

        latch.await();

        db = mongoClient.getDatabase("le_users");

        //Gets Table
        UserDataCollection = db.getCollection("UserData");
    }
```

Manfiest Permissions

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Called in OnCreate like this

```
 try {
            MongoDBConnection();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous Java driver relies on the AsynchronousSocketChannel class, which was introduced in Java 7, and from the stack trace it appears that that class in not available, at least not in the version of Android on which you're testing.

The asynchronous driver can also be used with [Netty](http://netty.io/) as an alternative to AsynchronousSocketChannel, so you might give that a try.  In the 3.0 driver it requires the setting of the "org.mongodb.async.type" system property to "netty", but in 3.1 there will be a way to do this programmatically as well.

Comment: I just switched to the regular one. But I'll come back here in the off chance I decide to switch back.